# Blocked Matrix Multiplication

Tags: matrix, lisp, common-lisp, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to create a function that performs blocked matrix multiplication in AllegroCL, but I keep getting array-index errors. I believe it is due to the indicies being 0-19 for a side of a 20 x 20 block matrix, but I'm unsure of how to fix it.

Error: Array index 20 too big for dimension 20 while accessing
       #.
[condition type: type-error]

Any help or direction is much appreciated. Below is my code thus far.

```
(defun bmmul (A B)
  (let* ((m (car (array-dimensions A)))
         (n (cadr (array-dimensions A)))
         (l (cadr (array-dimensions B)))
         (u 0)
         (C (make-array `(,m ,l) :initial-element 0)))
    (loop for p from 0 to (- m n) do
          (loop for i from (+ 0 1) to n do
                (setf u (aref C i 0))
                (loop for k from p to (- (+ p n) 1) do
                      (setf u (* (aref A i k) (aref B k 0))))
                (setf (aref C i 0) u)))
    C))
```

Comment: In `LOOP`, `to n` is inclusive. If you want to exclude `n`, use `below n` instead.

Answer (score 1):

In general, when looping over an array index, you go `:from 0 :below n`, where `n` is the array dimension, so when the dimension is 20, the index goes from 0 up to and including 19.

Another problem seems to be that in the innermost loop, you want to `incf`, not `setf`.  You also do not need a temporary variable (`u`) there, just `incf` the array cell directly.

Finally, I do not feel that you structured your loops correctly, I do not expect to see a hardcoded `0` index there.  The innermost loop body *should* look like `(incf (aref c i j) (* (aref a i k) (aref b k j)))`, regardless of whether you do ordinary or blocked multiplication.